# Is quantum entanglement the "architecture" for a quantum chip?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I am trying to understand the role of entanglement in quantum computing.  Is it a method used to link/entangle states of qubits so each state is dependent on it's entangled partner? And If entanglement is monogamous how do you entangle multiple states?

Answer (score 0):

Entanglement occurs whenever two or more quantum states are created in a single interaction. They need not be monogamous.  This doesn't answer your question of how to entangle multiple states, but it happens all the time in nature.  For example, all of the electrons in an atom in its ground state are entangled.  Not all entangled systems are easy to transform into quantum computers, however (except in the trivial case of self-simulation). For an extreme example of many-particle entanglement see [this current Phys Rev Letter](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.121.220404?utm_source=email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=prl-alert)